# Discriminant of a polynomial: a question about definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, discriminant

Let $f(x)$ be a non-constant polynomial of degree $n$ over a  field $F$ and $r_1,r_2,\ldots, r_n$ be its roots in some extension of $F$.

The discriminant of $f(x)$ is a symmetric expression in its roots, but, a little modification comes when the polynomial is non-monic.

(i) If $f(x)$ is monic, then discriminant is defined as $\prod_{i<j} (r_i-r_j)^2$.

(ii) If $f(x)$ has leading term $a_n(\neq 0)$, then its discriminant is defined as $a_n^{2n-2} \prod_{i<j} (r_i-r_j)^2$.

**Question** Why the modification for leading term $a_n$ in the definition of discriminant is done in above manner? (I mean, why discriminant is not defined simply by the expression of roots as above by ignoring leading term?) If we see further the connection of discriminant with resultant, the leading term still doesn't miss even if we include $a_n^{2n-2}$ in the discriminant expression since, by (ii), the following is connection with discriminant:
$$
\mbox{discriminant}(f)= \frac{(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}\mbox{Resultant}(f,f')}{a_n}.
$$

Comment: One reason is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4380830/discriminant-in-terms-of-roots#comment9156334_4380830). For example, with that factor, the discriminant of a polynomial in $\,\mathbb Z[x],$ is always in $\,\mathbb Z\,$ itself. Otherwise, if all you knew were integers and nothing about rationals, you could not calculate the discriminant of $\,4x^2-1\,$ with the first definition, because it would be in $\,\mathbb Q \setminus \mathbb Z\,$.

Comment: Is $2n-2$ the least power of $a_0$ which multiplied with $\prod_{i<j}(r_i-r_j)^2$ gives expression in $\mathbb{Z}$ for all polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed.